# Connect to MySQL with hashed password?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, connection

I was wondering (and used Google with no clear result) if there is any way to connect to a MySQL database with PHP using a hashed password. Say I have the following:

```
Password (plain): 'foobar'
Password (sha1): '8843d7f92416211de9ebb963ff4ce28125932878'
```

Now I would like to connect to MySQL like this (using the mysql_* function as example, I'm using PDO though):

```
$db_link = mysql_connect ( 'localhost', 'user', '8843d7f92416211de9ebb963ff4ce28125932878' );
```

I this possible? Have anyone done this before?

Comment: If someone has access to the code, then they can log in no matter what your password is. Just use a long randomly generated password, and don't display it to the user :-).

Comment: there's no point in doing that... if you want your users to have more "privacy" regarding their super-secret passwords, they should first run those super-secret keywords through any kind of a hash function and use that hash as their password

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no.

But, just wondering... what is your real concern? Someone hacking into your server and discovering your password?

Comment: Just privacy, would you like it when you (for example) sign up on a website without you're password being encrypted in the database?

Comment: The reason you should hash (not encryption) peoples passwords is not to protect their data, but to prevent hackers, who already have breached your security and have access to everything, from being able to take you login details and try to reuse it to access your details on other sites, such as email.

Just be wary of when you are walking the line between obfuscation and security.

Answer (score 11):

Then the "hash" would *be* the password. What would be the benefit?

Comment: So someone, even if they get the plain text connection data, wouldn't know the user's password.  Which would only matter if you use the same password on everything.

Comment: But since you as the cautious developer/admin are already concerned about this you wouldn't use this password also everywhere else ;-) And you have placed it somewhere not accessible through your webserver.

Comment: The benefit would be privacy. I'm developing an application which stores database connection values (in a 'master' database) for using the application.

Comment: I don't see the advantage. Let's assume MySQL has such a ...connect_with_passwordhash() function. I somehow get access to your master database and steal all your password hashes. Now, can't I simply feed them the to ...connect_with_passwordhash() like your script does?

Comment: That is true, though when it's THEORICALLY impossible to access the master MySQL database, it gives a user more privacy storing a password hashed. WHEN someone gets access to the master database, what's the point of stealing the password? All other databases (with other users and passwords) also run on the same server, why not copy all stuff immediatly?

It's just a privacy issue.. I know it's possible to get access with the plain password OR hash.

Comment: But you don't need another built-in mysql function for that. Build an account management system (/a web interface) that takes the plain password and then stores the hash in the "master database" and the other databases (as the password). That would also be a good opportunity to add some kind of password salt.

Answer (score 2):

the usage case would be having multiple developers editing the .php file that contains the sql connect password that you might not want them to know.

I think one solution would be to move the connect statement out to a file like so, make sure you don't have a $password variable though cause someone could just call it and print it out later in their .php file

```
mysql.php
<?php
    mysql_connect('db.cs.dal.ca','user','password');
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Database Error ".mysql_error());
?>
```

and only give your self rw------- permissions to the mysql.php file, then in all of your group accessible .php files you can just include that file to evoke a connection.

```
index.php
<?php include("mysql.php") ?>

<!-- some web content -->

<?php mysql_close(); ?>
```

and give your developers group rw-rw---- permissions on all the other .php files, as long as the owner of the mysql.php file can read it should executed on the php server..... i think.

you can also exclude mysql.php from git for example, and have developers run their own local copy of a DB with their own mysql.php file and just provide a stripped down copy of your production database for local development and testing

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer is **"You can't."**

I know what you are trying to accomplish: You are probably on some shared hosting plan and cannot put your config file above the html folder.

Stefan is thinking that a hacker would just be hunting for the config file and wants to make him have to work for the info. Once the hacker realizes he needs more info, he has to crack the site a second time.

This has nothing to do with a table of usernames & passwords. This is for the MySQL config file.